# Prove that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2-(4+a)\sin^2(x) - 2 a \sin^4(x)-a^2\sin^6(x)}{(1+a\sin^2(x))^{5/2}}dx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

Numerically, I found that the following holds (with errors in the order of $10^{-16}$): $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2-(4+a)\sin^2(x) - 2 a \sin^4(x)-a^2\sin^6(x)}{(1+a\sin^2(x))^{5/2}}dx=0
\quad \forall a>0$$

I tried to prove it but failed. The integrand doesn't seem to have any symmetric properties that make the integral trivial. Can anyone prove or disprove it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that the indefinite integral is given by $$-\frac{\sin (2 x) (a \cos (2 x)-a-4)}{\sqrt{2} (a (-\cos (2 x))+a+2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: what a ''useful'' answer..how do you get this result?

Comment: i integrate this and used the Weierstrass substituion

Comment: I would really like to see the Weierstrass substitution used for this problem. Could you show the steps ? I have not been able to do it; so I am very interested. Thank you.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Some people have mentioned that this answer was possibly obtained by Wolfram Alpha. Although not totally satisfactory, this answer is helpful. At least I can verify its derivative is the integrand.

Comment: @junjiema2. The **result does not matter as long as you don't know the way to get it**. Many CAS can do it; I solved it using differential equations but a CAS to finish. What I am almost sure is that Weierstrass substitution would be a nightmare (I spent hours with it for no result).  Please notice that, once more,  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner does not answer questions asked about his "solutions".

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thanks for your interests and efforts. I agree with you. This question still remains unanswered. I'm wondering what's the mechanism behind Wolfram Alpha. Such a nice and clean solution...

Comment: @junjiema2. If I may suggest, give your professor this result without any explanation. Tell me how he/she does react.